# C# HtmlDecode not decoding spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string in an ASP.NET web app which is causing an exception to be thrown because the code expects a regular string but it is HTML encoded, like this:

```
This&#32;is&#32;a&#32;string
```

I understand that the `&#32;` corresponds to a single space. In order to resolve the issue I am trying to use the `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` method. However, the string that comes out is identical, so the code still fails. The line in question looks like this:

```
var names = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(this.titles).Split(',');
```

Is there a problem with the way I am using the method? From what I gather in the documentation this should be correct.

Comment: not reproduceable https://dotnetfiddle.net/eI3Q9z

Comment: I can't reproduce this in .NET Old or .NET Core. `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("Hi&#32;there")` returns `Hi there`. Are you sure this is the actual input? Perhaps the string is double-encoded? Or contains invisible characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. There was a bug elsewhere in the code where the string was being re-encoded by AntiXssEncoder. So every time it ran it was reencoding before saving the string, and the `&` characters were being converted to `&amp;`.

I simply added a `WebUtility.HtmlDecode()` at the re-encode step and it was fixed.